# How a multiple select MySQL query works

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about something basic related to mysql. consider a query like:

```
select * 
  from logdb_new.new_tbl_logrecord as alltable 
  where alltable.SessionID in (
    select distinct SessionID from logdb_new.new_tbl_health
  )
```

I wonder if an index on `SessionID` of `new_tbl_health` table is used during execution of this query. In other words tell me if the second part of the query, `select distinct SessionID from logdb_new.new_tbl_health`, first executed generating a list and then the main query executes or it uses an index or whatever on `new_tbl_health` to find sessionIDs for every row of new_tbl_logrecord.

I want to reduce execution time of my query. logdb_new.new_tbl_logrecord has almost 30 million records and distinct SessionIDs of logdb_new.new_tbl_health 
are more than 80 thousand results. Please let me know if there is a better query instead to reduce execution time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that an index on `new_tbl_health.SessionID` can be used here, because the result of your subquery is an intermediate result.  But, we can try rewriting your query using an inner join:

```
SELECT *
FROM logdb_new.new_tbl_logrecord t1
INNER JOIN logdb_new.new_tbl_health t2
    ON t1.SessionID = t2.SessionID;
```

Besides that the index might be usable here, the advantage to an inner join version is that the optimizer is now free to choose which table appears on the left/right sides of the join.

As a side note, if you want to stick with your current approach, I think you can drop the distinct select and just use:

```
SELECT SessionID FROM logdb_new.new_tbl_health
```

If duplicate `SessionID` values arise, it won't logically change the outcome of your query.  But invoking `DISTINCT` would mean the query plan would probably have to do some aggregating, perhaps unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, I think the join gives more flexibility to the optimizer to choose the execution plan.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks for "sticking" me with that comment, no pun intended :-)

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen . I will try join version to see if it takes less time.

Comment: I think that removing distinct from new_tbl_health won't necessarily lead to a faster query plan. It depends to the size of the final resultset and to the number of duplicates in new_tbl_health. For example, if with 80K distinct values in new_tbl_health the final result size will be 10M tuples, then if all values in new_tbl_health (without distinct) are 800K, this will lead to a huge final result with 100M tuples, and probably with that many duplicates you will need to perform duplicate elimination to that final result.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think an index on the subquery will be used with `in` (although optimizers do sometimes do amazing things).  But, you can use `exists` instead, which will use the index:

```
select lr.* 
from logdb_new.new_tbl_logrecord lr
where exists (select 1
              from logdb_new.new_tbl_health nth
              where lr.SessionID = nth.SessionID
             );
```

Comment: "...although optimizers do sometimes do amazing things..." -- Oracle does a few interesting things.

Answer (score 1):

The query:

```
select distinct SessionID from logdb_new.new_tbl_health
```

is a "non-correlated subquery". Most (if not all) databases will execute it first, to get the list of IDs and will use this list to select rows from the outer query.

The down side is that this query cannot be "pipelined" as it is, so it will need to materialize the whole set of id values. If you used a `JOIN` instead, the query could have been pipelined, and would require much less memory. Anyway, this kind of optimization is significant only when the number of ids returned by the subquery is massive; I wouldn't worry otherwise.